# Official Android SDK WebSocket API

Tags: android, websocket

Is it possible Android SDK does not provide an officially supported WebSocket API, so people don't have to google around looking at a variety of 3rd party libraries provided for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android SDK does not provide an officially supported WebSocket API

Correct. The Android SDK does not provide a Java WebSocket API. `WebView` supports WebSockets, though I'm not sure how far back that support goes.

Comment: So what is their response to having to connect to a websocket-based json service and persist the connection for the lifetime of an app running in foreground? If I rely on pure tcp/ip I have to take care manually of http headers and packets of data potentially cut into chunks etc.

Comment: @DarkoMaksimovic: "So what is their response to having to connect to a websocket-based json service and persist the connection for the lifetime of an app running in foreground?" -- presumably, use a third-party library, though you would have to ask Google. I think koush's [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) is a fairly popular implementation. I have used its server-side API in an Android app with success, though I haven't tried the more traditional client-side API.

Answer (score -1):

http://kaazing.org/   Native Android (and Java) WS client.  And the JS WS client is there too; it uses native WS or emulates it in older browsers.   Its all open-source in Github.

Full disclosure.  I work for Kaazing.